# Function executing as constructor, but not as function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've the following code in my displayandmove.as file:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class FigureConstruct extends MovieClip {

        public function displayandmove() {
            this.height = stage.stageHeight/5;
            this.width = stage.stageWidth/5;
        }

    }

}
```

And I have the following on frame 1 of my displayandmove.fla:

```
var figure:FigureConstruct = new FigureConstruct();
stage.addChild(figure);
figure.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
figure.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
```

These files are in the same directory. In my FLA library I have my figure MovieClip and it ha a Class of "FigureConstruct" and base class of "flash.display.MovieClip".

Currently the code above works fine because I figured out that if I execute the object size code as a construct -- using the file name as the function name -- it works.

What I originally intended to do was to have my function named "sizeFigure()" in my AS file and then call "figure.sizeFigure();" after "stage.addChild(figure);" on frame 1 of my FLA.

This output

> Error #1006: value is not a function.

Can anyone explain what I am missing to get this to execute as a function rather than as a constructor?

I thought maybe I am goofing up when I set my Class and Base Class pointers for the library object... but not sure.

PS - Sorry if I am misusing terms, still nailing those down as I go.

**Edit: Below is the original code that does not seem to work until after I changed the name of my function to the name of the file, making it the class constructor. The above version works, below does not.**

displayandmove.as

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class FigureConstruct extends MovieClip {

        public function sizeFigure() {
            this.height = stage.stageHeight/5;
            this.width = stage.stageWidth/5;
        }

    }

}
```

displayandmove.fla:

```
var figure:FigureConstruct = new FigureConstruct();
stage.addChild(figure);
figure.sizeFigure();
figure.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
figure.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error #1006: value is not a function

This [error](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/runtimeErrors.html) is occurring somewhere else in your code. Does that class have a property (function get/set) by the name `value`? And are you trying to access it as a function? Check your code for `value()` and replace it with `value`.

Comment: I added the code to my original post where I was just trying to use a method within my class to resize the object.

Do you mean the ()'s may need to be removed? This is all the code that I am currently working with.

Comment: `public class FigureConstruct` **must** be declared in `FigureConstruct.as` and not in displayandmove.as

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Once I changed my AS file name to match the specified Class I was able to run the function as sizeFigure().

This connected quite a few dots for me.

Comment: A `public class` should always be declared in a `.as` file with exactly the same name as the class. I somehow missed the fact that the names don't match when I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works, I have it set up like you have.

```
package {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;

        public class FigureConstruct extends MovieClip {

            public function displayandmove():void
            {
                height = stage.stageHeight/5;
                width = stage.stageWidth/5;
            }


            public function sizeFigure():void
            {
                x = stage.stageWidth/2;
                y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            }
        }
    }
```